# Rails Omniauth-github (422) The change you wanted was rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, github-api

I have had [this solution](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth-revised?view=asciicast) for Omniauth & Github implemented and working fine but sometime in the last few months it stopped working.

The error I'm getting when I try to login is: (422) The change you wanted was rejected.

Specifically in the Heroku logs I'm seeing:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Password can't be blank):
app/models/user.rb:18:in `create_from_omniauth'
app/models/user.rb:14:in `from_omniauth'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:4:in `create'
```

Do I need to save the credentials when I create the user?

My user model:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice("provider", "uid")).first || create_from_omniauth(auth)
end

def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.name = auth["info"]["nickname"]
    user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
    user.image = auth["info"]["image"]
 end
end
```

Sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in!"
end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed out!"
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're either validating presence of the password field in your `User` model or using `has_secure_password`, which does that under the covers.

If you're doing that validation yourself, you can just add a clause like `:if => :password_changed?` to the validation.

If you're using `has_secure_password`, it depends which version of Rails you're using. Any version with [these](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0e1e527654f286452fa6f86f5d229f278435319a) [two](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0e1e527654f286452fa6f86f5d229f278435319a) changes (I believe only Rails 4) support passing a `validations: false` option to `has_secure_password`. Otherwise, there's not really a good solution, other than maybe setting a random dummy password when you create the user then letting them change it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

**Facebook's omniauth error "the change you wanted was rejected"**
might appear because of your validations set in the model. I had to refactor my validation for users having one unique email, which wasn't working when a user would try to facebook login with the same email.

Look at your logs. `heroku logs -t`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when the time on my gitlab server was out of sync, i restarted ntpd, which corrected the time on the server and the problem was resolved